# Isabelle/jEdit just starts with ~/Scratch.thy (or does not launch) by clicking .thy file or using open command in MacOS

Tags: macos, isabelle

Recently, I restarted playing with Isabelle/HOL.
However, I faced the following problem in MacOS (Monterey):
When I click `foo.thy` file, Isabelle/jEdit launches but ignores `foo.thy` and starts with `~/Scratch.thy`. The same happens when I uses `open foo.thy` from terminal.

(Also, in MacOS Catalina, Isabelle/jEdit cannot be launched by clicking a file (it tries to launch in the sense that the icon hops in Dock, but after some seconds, it stops), though I cannot re-check it since I've already upgraded MacOS.)

How can I open a theory file by clicking the file?

Some additional information (these are under Monterey):

1. My Isabelle/jEdit is of Isabelle2021-1 from [Isabelle's official site](https://isabelle.in.tum.de).
2. I checked Isabelle/jEdit can be launched by clicking `Isabelle2021-1.app`.
3. After launching Isabelle/jEdit, I can open files from `File > Open...` in the Menu bar.
4. I can open foo.thy directly by `/Applications/Isabelle2021-1.app/bin/isabelle jedit foo.thy`.
5. When I launch by clicking a file named `Chapter01.thy`, then the activity log includes

```
12:06:08 PM [main] [message] jEdit: starting with command line arguments: -settings=/Users/suzuyu/.isabelle/Isabelle2021-1/jedit -server=Isabelle2021-1 -reuseview -nobackground -nosplash -log=9 /Users/suzuyu/Scratch.thy
```

so, it seems that the file is already ignored at this stage.

Comment: There is also the 'File Browser' menu to the left in jEdit to open a file. I always open the file I want to edit once and then Ctrl+Click to other files in the project.